# Can we normalize the terminology used on the Tag Synonym pages?

Tags: bug, terminology, user-interface

I always run into this problem when I go to create a tag synonym. On the page that lists synonyms, the nice, clear, and useful terms **Master** and **Synonym**. However, on the *Create Tag Synonym* page, different and more ambiguous terminology is used: **Target Tag** and **Source Tag**. I can see two ways of interpreting this more ambiguous terminology:

- *Target* is the Synonym for the Master *Source*
- *Target* is the Master for the new *Source* Synonym

Crop it up to the kind of inane issues I have to deal with in my day job on a regular basis, and the kinds of wacko problems that occur due to ambiguity, and the necessity of seeing both sides of the story when such issues arise....anyway.

Could we use the same terms on the Create Synonym page as on the listing page: Master and Synonym? That eliminates any ambiguity.

Comment: Hell yes, confuses me too.